# Postsharp Recordable and NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: postsharp

I am using the "standard" NotifyPropertyChanged aspect in combination with Recordable, which works fine.

Now I want to check the changes for my custom dirty logic. 
To do so, I have written a custom aspect that uses

```
[OnLocationSetValueAdvice, MulticastPointcut(Targets = MulticastTargets.Property)]
public void OnPropertySet(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
```

This method gets called when manually changing a property, but is not called on performing an undo, which seems strange to me.

How can I catch changes coming from undo, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostSharp's `[Recordable]` records change on the level of fields, not of properties, and therefore your aspect is skipped during undo/redo. You should apply it to fields and order it *after* `Recordable`.

Alternatively, you can implement the [callback interface](http://doc.postsharp.net/undoredo-callbacks).